# Sencha Touch: how to get config from tpl?

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

With Sencha Touch, I created a component to display a table for my mobile application.

Here's my component code:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.components.table.Table', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    xtype: 'table',

    config: {
    cls: 'myTableCSS',
    scrollable: 'vertical',
    tpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate',
        '<tpl for=".">',
            '<table>',
                '<tr>',
                    '<tpl for="headers">',
                        '<th>{html}</th>',
                    '</tpl>',
                '</tr>',
                '<tpl for="rows">',
                    '<tr class="{[this.config.id]}" >',
                        '<tpl for="columns">',
                                '<td>{html}</td>',
                        '</tpl>',
                    '</tr>',
                '</tpl>',
            '</table>',
        '</tpl>'
    }
});
```

Here's my view implementation:

```
xtype: 'table',
id: 'myRedTable',
data: [
    {
        headers: [
            { html: 'firstname' },
            { html: 'lastname' },
            { html: 'age' }
        ],
        rows: [
            {
                columns: [
                    { html: 'John' },
                    { html: 'Smith' },
                    { html: '38' },
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
],
```

In my component, when I use `{[this.config.id]}` I would like to get the id of my view implementation (i.e. `myRedTable`) but it doesn't work.

Is there any solution to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you wrote the syntax for inline arbitrary code correctly, but there's a problem with scope. `this` refers to the instance of `Ext.XTemplate` itself, not the table view.

You should try another way to get the reference of your table instance instead, for example, in your table's definition file:

```
initialize: function(){
    var me = this;
    me.setTpl('Ext.XTemplate',
        // blah blah ...
        // now you can use "me" to refer to your table instance
    )
}
```